# Why is the Except:ValueError not working in my code?

Tags: python, typeerror, valueerror

This is my source code:

```
def farmer_johns():

    r = int(input('Enter the radius of the circle in feet:'))
    #check for valid input
    try:
        while input >= 0 :
        # area of brown
        #area of square - area of circle
            import math

            pi = math.pi
            area_square = (r+r)**2
            area_circle = pi* r**2

            area_brown = area_square - area_circle
            print('The area of the brown shaded region is {:.2f} feet^2.'.format(area_brown))


            #turtle graphics set up
            import turtle
            wn = turtle.Screen()
            a = turtle.Turtle()
            a.pensize(5)

            #draw circles
            a.pencolor('green')

            a.penup()
            a.goto(r,r)
            a.pendown()
            a.circle(r)

            a.penup()
            a.goto(r,-r)
            a.pendown()
            a.circle(r)

            a.penup()
            a.goto(-r,-r)
            a.pendown()
            a.circle(r)

            a.penup()
            a.goto(-r,r)
            a.pendown()
            a.circle(r)

             #square
             a.pencolor('blue')

             a.penup()
             a.goto(r,r+r)
             a.pendown()
             a.goto(-r,r+r)
             a.goto(-r,-r+r)
             a.goto(r,-r+r)
             a.goto(r,r+r)

             #middle region
             a.pencolor('#654321')
             a.fillcolor('#b5651d')
             a.begin_fill()

             a.penup()
             a.goto(r,r)
             a.pendown()
             a.circle(r,-90)

             a.penup()
             a.goto(0,r+r)
             a.right(180)
             a.pendown()
             a.circle(r,-90)

             a.penup()
             a.goto(-r,r)
             a.left(-180)
             a.pendown()
             a.circle(r,-90)

             a.penup()
             a.goto(0,0)
             a.left(180)
             a.pendown()
             a.circle(r,-90)

             a.end_fill()

             #writing

             # a.write('The area of the brown shaded region is {:.2f} feet^2.'.format(area_brown))

    except ValueError:
        print('invaild input')
    except TypeError:
        print('invaild input')
```

The problem is when I enter in letters as a input I get this:

> > > farmer_johns()
> > >       Enter the radius of the circle in feet:Ee
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\SueAnn\Desktop\Comp Sci\Projects\project_3\farmer john again.py", line 19, in farmer_johns
> > >           r = int(input('Enter the radius of the circle in feet:'))
> > >       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Ee'

The "Except:TypeError" line  of code works but the 'Except: ValueError

Comment: The exception is outside of your ``try...except`` block.

Comment: What do you *expect* from `int('Ee')` ?

Comment: I would expect it to print "invalid input'.

Comment: Also if I indent the line that says 'Except ValueError' so it is inside the try...except block then the code won't even run. It says it's 'invalid syntax'.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Why is the Except:ValueError not working in my code?

As 'Mike Scotty' pointed out, you are `try .. except` the wrong line of code!

> **Note**: `try .. except` **only one** line of code!
>   This gives you control, over which line of code throws the Exception.

Change to the following:

```
def farmer_johns():
    #check for valid input
    # This try ... except catches: input value != integer
    try:
        r = int(input('Enter the radius of the circle in feet:'))
    except ValueError as e:
        print('invaild input: {}'.format(e)

    ## Other code follows
```

> This will raise an Error, as there is **no** variable `input` defined!
>
> ```
> while input >= 0 :
> ```

You can use `while True:` in conjunction with `break`.